# Question about screen rotation in Rpi

Tags: raspbian, vnc

I've a few questions regarding screen_rotation. Since I'm running a headless Rpi, I can't test it on my own. I prefer someone experienced to answer the question.

1. If I set "display_rotate = 1" in config.txt in boot, does it get reflected in my tvservice -s output ?
2. If I set "display_rotate = 1" in config.txt and iconnect to my rpi via VNC (remote desktop), do I get rotated display ?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No tvservice -s output will be the same regardless of screen orientation.
2. No. Virtual sessions are not affected by config.txt graphics settings.

Comment: I reached the same conclusion. :)